Understanding equation for eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian
I'm reading the paper Hamiltonian Truncation Study of Supersymmetric
Quantum Mechanics. I'm not understanding a claim they make about the eigenvalues of a certain Hamiltonian. In particular, how eqn 3.6 follows from eqn 3.5.
We have an $N \times N$ Hamiltonian, where
\begin{align*}
    H_{nm} &= (\frac{n \pi}{L})^2\delta_{nm} + \frac{2c}{L} \sin{\frac{n \pi a}{L}} \sin{\frac{m \pi a}{L}}.
\end{align*}
Apparently, the eigenvalues of this are given by the solutions of
\begin{align*}
    f(E) &= 1 + \frac{2c}{L}\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{(\sin{\frac{n \pi a}{L}})^2}{(\frac{n \pi}{L})^2 - E} = 0.
\end{align*}
I don't see how to deduce this.
I thought the condition would be,
\begin{align*}
    det{((\frac{n \pi}{L})^2 - E)\delta_{nm} + \frac{2c}{L} \sin{\frac{n \pi a}{L}} \sin{\frac{m \pi a}{L}}}) &= 0.
\end{align*}
Am I mistaken?

I suspect this is just a rewriting of the characteristic equation (i.e., the determinant you've specified), rewritten by dividing by the product $\prod_{i=1}^N\left(\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2-E\right)$. It also looks like it could be related to the resolvent of the matrix.

I agree that it looks something like that. But I don't see how they get the specific formula they have.

Have you tried to write down a general expression for this determinant, manipulated it, and seen if you can make it work?  I tried it out for a 2-by-2 version, and it works. Here's some Mathematica code to show that it works for $N=5$ (and for general $N$ by changing the value of nn). But really, this is just a mathematical manipulation, so I suspect this is off-topic here.

I thought I had some conceptual error. It still seems like that if mine and their expressions are equivalent, that there should be straighforward way to see it, and I couldn't find it.

Try slugging through explicitly for a small N?

The expression for the determinant of a square matrix $M$ of size $N$ is
$$\det M = \sum_{\sigma \in S_N} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)M_{1,\sigma(1)}\ldots M_{N,\sigma(N)}.$$
In this case, $M_{mn} = A_n\delta_{mn} + B_{mn}$, where
$$A_n = \left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2-E \\ 
B_{mn} = \frac{2c}{L}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi a}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi a}{L}\right).$$
Therefore, the expression expands out to
$$\det M = \sum_{\sigma \in S_N} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)(A_1\delta_{1,\sigma(1)} + B_{1,\sigma(1)})\ldots(A_N\delta_{N,\sigma(N)} + B_{N,\sigma(N)}).$$
We can group these $2^N$ terms per summand into $N+1$ categories, where the $n \choose r$ terms in category $r$ has exactly $r$ factors of $B$ and $n-r$ factors of $A$. Therefore, this becomes
$$\det M = \sum_{\sigma \in S_N} \sum_{r=0}^N \sum_{\{i_1\ldots i_r\} \subset\{1\ldots N\}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) B_{i_{1},\sigma(i_1)}\ldots B_{i_r,\sigma(i_r)} A_{i_{r+1}}\delta_{i_{r+1},\sigma(i_{r+1})}\ldots A_{i_N}\delta_{i_N,\sigma(i_N)} \\ = \sum_{r=0}^N \sum_{\{i_1\ldots i_r\} \subset\{1\ldots N\}}\sum_{\sigma \in S_N}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) B_{i_{1},\sigma(i_1)}\ldots B_{i_r,\sigma(i_r)} A_{i_{r+1}}\delta_{i_{r+1},\sigma(i_{r+1})}\ldots A_{i_N}\delta_{i_N,\sigma(i_N)}.$$
Because of the deltas, the only nonzero permutations for each $r$ are the ones that permute only $\{i_1\ldots i_r\}$ within themselves. So this becomes
$$\det M = \sum_{r=0}^N \sum_{\{i_1\ldots i_r\} \subset\{1\ldots N\}}\sum_{\sigma \in S{\{i_1 \ldots i_r\}}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) B_{i_{1},\sigma(i_1)}\ldots B_{i_r,\sigma(i_r)} A_{i_{r+1}}\ldots A_{i_N}.$$
The next observation is that any product of $B$'s is invariant under permutation of indices. I believe you can take it from here.
